# Springboot rest template fetch limited rows

Tags: java

I am working on a backend service that uses Spring boot rest template to query an external service, and show the response. I want to set some conditions on the results returned. The response is a list, and I want to return 0 results if there are less than 3 records available. If there are 3 or more, then I want to return 3 records. How do I achieve this? Any tips will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to control the responses is to use `Interceptors`. You can update the response, before its returned to client.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors
          = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new MyRestTemplateInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
```

And in interceptor, you can add your custom logic,

```
public class MyRestTemplateInterceptor
            implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
                HttpRequest request,
                byte[] body,
                ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

            ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
            //update the response to send the required records
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A "rest template" would return a ResponseEntity (org.springframework.http)

Lets say the response is something like

```
[
  {
    "idGear": "1",
    "name": "lala"
  }, {
    "idGear": "2",
    "name": "lala2"
  }
]
```

Create a Java pojo class:

```
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        class Product {
        String idGear;
        String name;
        //Add Getter, Setters, Contructors 
        }
```

Now, fetch the response into array

```
ResponseEntity<Product[]> response =
  restTemplate.getForEntity("<URL>",Product[].class);
Product[] productResponse = response.getBody();
```

Now, you can easily check the response and return accordingly

```
Product[] products = null;
if(null != productResponse && productResponse.length > 3){
  products = new Product[]{productResponse[0], productResponse[1], productResponse[2]};
}else {
 products = new Product[]{};
}
return products;
```